# Injective matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix of non-negative reals with columns that sum to $1.$ I would like know the necessary and sufficient conditions for $A$ to be such that for any $n\times1$ matrices $x$ and $y,$ with entries summing  to $1,$ we have that $Ax=Ay$ implies $x=y.$

Also, information about related concepts in linear algebra or probability theory would be appreciated.

Comment: stochastic matrices are necessarily square, so this post needs a significant re-write

Comment: I have rewritten the question as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition it is sufficient for $A$ to be injective i.e. all columns linearly independent.  This is necessary as well.

for any non-zero $\mathbf w \in \ker A$ via rescaling we can ensure $\big \Vert \mathbf w \big \Vert_1 = 2$  (i.e. an L1 norm of 2) and
$A\mathbf w = \mathbf 0\implies 0=\mathbf 1_m^T \mathbf 0=\mathbf 1_m^T\big(A\mathbf w\big) =\big(\mathbf 1_m^TA\big)\mathbf w=\mathbf 1_n^T\mathbf w$

Then $\mathbf w = \mathbf x - \mathbf y$
where $\mathbf x$ has all the positive components of $\mathbf w$ and zeroes everywhere else and $-\mathbf y$ has all the negative components of $\mathbf w$ and zeroes everywhere else.  Since $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ are real non-negative vectors we have $0=\mathbf 1_n^T\mathbf w = \mathbf 1_n^T\mathbf x -\mathbf 1_n^T\mathbf y= \big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_1-\big \Vert \mathbf y\big \Vert_1$
and
$2=\big \Vert \mathbf w\big \Vert_1=\big \Vert \mathbf x-\mathbf y\big \Vert_1=\big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_1+\big \Vert \mathbf y\big \Vert_1=2$
$\implies \big \Vert \mathbf y\big \Vert_1 = 1 = \big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_1$ as desired

The only way to ensure we can never find such a $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ is to insist that

$\ker A=\big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$
i.e. that $A$ is injective aka has a left-inverse aka has all columns linearly independent aka $m\geq n$ with no singular values equal to zero.